# JPA query for 3 tables

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, jpa-2.0

I want to create JPA query for configuring multiple Terminals to one Contract:

```
CREATE TABLE `contracts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `contracts_terminals` (
  `terminal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `terminals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How I can create JPA query which uses table contracts_terminals to assign multiple terminals to one contract?

I use latest MariaDB.

Entities:

Contracts:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "contracts")
    public class Contracts implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3873648042962238717L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private int id;

        @Column(length = 255)
        private String name;    
        ......
    }
```

Terminals:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "terminals")
    public class Terminals implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5288308199642977991L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 3)
        private int id;

        @Column(length = 255)
        private String name;
        ....
    }
```

ContractTerminals:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract_terminals")
public class ContractTerminals implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1191148141983861602L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer terminal_id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer contract_id;
    ....
}
```

Comment: If this is a JPA question, the model classes would  be useful.

Comment: @AlanHay Done. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Where are the relations? `@OneToMany`? One (`ContractTerminals`) is seemingly a join table, so should NOT be not an entity in its own right. Any JPA docs show you how to do that. Also your join entity has 2 columns only, and you seem to want to map it have some "id" as well as the 2 FKs! http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_join_uni

Comment: Can you show me how to do it without @OneToMany relation and without it's own entity?

Comment: Why would you do that? It's a dumb thing to do. If you want to hack such systems just use JDBC, there are ample tutorials on the web for that

Comment: Can you show me please?